# How to use this POST CURL into PHP

Tags: php, curl, post

```
EXCLAMATION_MARK='!'
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID/Messages.json \
--data-urlencode "From=whatsapp:$$$$$" \
--data-urlencode "Body=Hello there$EXCLAMATION_MARK" \
--data-urlencode "To=whatsapp:+$$$$$" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

Hey all,
how can I use this curl code in PHP code?
i have been tried a lot of options but non was succeed

Comment: Maybe https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ should help

Comment: People will be able to help you a lot better if you show some of the options you tried, along with any errors you got when you tried them

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like.

```
$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID="whatever";
$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN="FLEH";
$ch = curl_init("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}/Messages.json");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array(
    "From"=>"whatsapp:\$\$\$\$\$",
    "Body"=>"Hello there!",
    "To"=>"whatsapp:+\$\$\$\$\$"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```